# JavaScript 'beforeunload' event not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to open a pop-out window, then after close pop-out window (refresh a parent page)

jquery 'beforeunload' event not working in internet explorer 8,9.

my code is:

```
 /*
  * events
  * add tallyman
  */
 $("div.main form div.tallymanlist").click(function() {
     if(gencargo.show_confirm('Add  new tallyman?')) {
         var windowObject = gencargo.windowOpener(600,1400, "Tallyman",$(this).children().attr("url"));
         gencargo.windowParentRefresh(windowObject);
     }
 });
```

gencargo object is content (window open):

```
    /*
     *  open  window 
     */
    windowOpener : function (windowHeight, windowWidth, windowName, windowUri) {
        var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
        var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;

        newWindow = window.open(windowUri, windowName, 'resizable=0,width=' + windowWidth + 
            ',height=' + windowHeight + 
            ',left=' + centerWidth + 
            ',top=' + centerHeight);

        newWindow.focus();
        return newWindow;
    },
```

and also window close:

```
    windowParentRefresh : function(object) {

      $(object).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            object.opener.location.reload();
      });
    }
```

Close window event is not working in ie.  Only in FireFox, Chrome, Opera.

Comment: yes. I have tried it. but it`s still not working in ie

Comment: It seems to work OK for me on IE 9, but not in IE 8 (IE 9 in IE 8 mode).  http://jsfiddle.net/DQfMH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 /*
  * reload page
 */
     windowParentRefresh: function(object) {

          setTimeout(function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
            $(object).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                object.opener.location.reload();
            });
              }, 1000);
          },1);

     }
```

Comment: oo thx!! timeout... awesome..I don`t know how it`s works, but it`s works!

Comment: Please post an explanation or link to an explanation on why adding a timeout would solve the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is over five years old, but I recently had to solve the same problem.  I was using this code just fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera using jQuery 3.1.1:

```
var myWindow = window.open(...);
$(myWindow).on('beforeunload', function () {
    ...
});
```

This did not work on IE 11 however.  I believe the cause is that event binding isn't possible until the child window has finished loading.  I discovered this when I found it worked after I put a breakpoint on the `$().on` line.  Breaking there gave the child window the time it needed to load.

Here's how I solved it:
In the **child window's code**, I added this line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.childWindowReady = true;
});
```

Then in my parent window, I use this code:

```
var myWindow = window.open(...),
    windowCheckInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (myWindow.childWindowReady) {
            $(myWindow).on('beforeunload', function () {
                ...
            });
            clearInterval(windowCheckInterval);
        }
    }, 500);
```

This way, I wait until the child window is ready, and I know it because my custom variable has been defined.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery API specifically says not to bind to beforeunload, instead bind directly to the window.onbeforeunload.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

window.onbeforeunload = askUser ;

function askUser(){
  return "Do you wanna quit?";

}
</script>
```

Comment: windowParentRefresh : function(object) {

   object.onbeforeunload = function() {
    object.opener.location.reload();
   }; 
  } I tried this, still not working ie ie :(

Comment: windowParentRefresh : function(object) { 
 alert('closed!!');
 object.onbeforeunload = function() {
  object.opener.location.reload(); 
 }; 
} . I see an alert, before my page is still  loading  (in ie), but after close it`s not working ofcourse

Comment: Where in the jQuery API does it (specifically) say I can't bind to beforeunload?  It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZWrh/

Comment: http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/